# AUTHENTICATION PASSWORD UNKNOWN

Tags: 12.04, password, authentication

I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I do not know my authentication password due to which i cannot install any software. Its urgent. Please tell me a solution and not a suggestion. In case , if I have set the password and forgotten it, what do I do to remove the existing password?

Answer (score 1):

"Boot up the machine,and after the BIOS screen, hold down the left Shift key." Did indeed NOT log you into the machine. That is correct. You are seeing a menu instead. If not, then don't read any further and try again.

If you do see the menu: Choose "Advanced options", then choose (recovery) from the menu. Then you see a lot of text passing upward on the screen. Do nothing. Then you see a colored menu. Choose "root".

Type:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
passwd your_username_here
```

change your password

then type:

```
reboot
```

[Source of Screenshots](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)